# Are iTunes Connect admins Testflight internal testers by default?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I added 3 users as **Internal testers** in *Users and Roles > TestFlight Beta Testers*.

In *My Apps > Prerelease > Internal Testers* only 2 of them appear.

The missing tester is an *Admin/Legal* user. They haven't received the TestFlight email invitation.

Are iTunes Connect admins Testflight internal testers by default? If not, did I miss any step in the process of getting them invited + added + receiving new builds in the Testflight app?

Comment: The problem may be that the missing tester is an account with two email addresses associated to it. One address is listed as Internal Tester, the other as External Tester. I invited the email address listed as External Tester to become an iTunesConnect user, and that seems to have unlocked the situation but I'll confirm later.

Answer (score 0):

Under the 2nd path you described, the listed testers have a status showing whether they accepted their invitation. Also there is the tab named something like *Current Build* there you can see if they have installed your app (and which version they are on of course).

The people showing up are not necessarily invited yet, you have to check the checkmark left to their AppleID to activate them for the current app and thereby invite them.

Comment: Thanks @Linus, see my comment to the question.